# PHP - Removing weird characters from XML

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap

I have looking around this site and none of the methods solve my problem.
Basically I got this XML from a SOAP response via cURL.
Problem is, it got some weird characters at the beginning & ending of the response.

Below is the screenshot of the XML response:
[image]

Not sure what went wrong in my code, please have a look

```
<?php
// error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL - E_NOTICE); 
ini_set('display_errors','On');

//header('Content-type: text/xml');

$soapUrl = "https://eins2.zurich.com.my/VIXAPI/VixService.svc?wsdl"; //URL of WSDL

// xml post structure

$xml_post_string = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:fnGetVehicleDtlsByVIX>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:VehInputInfo>{"AgentCode":"D02940-000","ParticipantCode":"06","RequestDateTime":"2017-Mar-17 11:00:00 PM","ID":"850321-07-5179","VehNo":"WA823H","Signature":"E448A5DE70160A7C541306B38ABAE3C8826ACD262DF217F9AA8B32244374C5E2E66D26D31874BBD832E43A6A569D20F2DFE8F674AECCFD698850BEBFB13767FD"}</tem:VehInputInfo>
      </tem:fnGetVehicleDtlsByVIX>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';


$headers = array(
            "POST: https://eins2.zurich.com.my/VIXAPI/VixService.svc HTTP/1.1",
            "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"UTF-8\"",
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Pragma: no-cache",
            "SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/IVixService/fnGetVehicleDtlsByVIX\"", 
            "Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
            "Host: eins2.zurich.com.my",
            "Connection: Keep-Alive"
        );
$url = $soapUrl;

//print_r($headers);

// PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword); // username and password - declared at the top of the doc
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// converting
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

print_r($response);
    ?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: substr() could probably fix it, but do `$response = curl_exec($ch);var_dump(base64_encode($response));` , what do you get? - you're dealing with binary data here, you should actually inspect it in a hex editor to find out exactly how many bytes are prepended & appended, and use substr() to remove them

Comment: @hanshenrik i tried the base64_encode command and i got "string(1492) bla bla bla...". dont really understand about the hex editor that u mentioned.

Comment: is there sensitive data in the response? if not, just paste the whole base64 on fpaste.org and post a link

Comment: @hanshenrik this is the generated response after i run the base64_encode. i really have no idea what this means, appreciate your help.
https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/PUb-Lvlfl8OsiwGI5RQddw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first contact the eins2.zurich.com.my guys and report this, as a bug in their server, and they should fix it. the problem is making your code work until they fix it..

i can immediately think of 2 solutions,

1: if the number of unwanted bytes are constant, you can inspect the response with a hex editor (like [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)) to count how many unwanted bytes there are, then use substr() to remove them. 
[image]

here i count 15 unwanted bytes at the start of the string, and
[image]

here i count 8 unwanted bytes at the end of the string. 
if it's ALWAYS 15 bytes + 8 bytes, you can fix it like this:

```
$response=substr($response,15,-8);
```

see https://3v4l.org/UURms

- BUT that won't work if the number of unwanted bytes is variable,
  which leads me to solution #2

if the unwanted bytes never contains `<` nor `>` then you can use strpos() to find the first `<`, and strrpos() to find the last `<`, and use substr() to remove everything before & after..

eg

```
$response=substr($response,strpos($response,'<'));
$response=substr($response,0,strrpos($response,'>')+1);
```

(or if you want a one-liner... `$response=substr(($response=substr($response,strpos($response,'<'))),0,strrpos($response,'>')+1);` , but no, don't do that.)

eg https://3v4l.org/Q8JiC

- BUT that won't work if the unwanted bytes contains `<` or `>`... if they do contain those, and the number of unwanted bytes are variable, then i can't think of a solution right now..

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It solved my problem as for now.
But I will keep looking what actually causing the problem. I doubt its the service provider's fault since there are others using the same SOAP server.
anyway thanks again.

Comment: @s3polz - well, you do handle compression incorrectly, what happens if you remove `"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",` and remove `"Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),` ?

Comment: @s3polz haha yeah that's it actually, you don't handle `Content-Encoding: gzip` correctly, and the server adds the gzip headers :P remove `"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",` and remove `"Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),` and add `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'');`, and it should fix the problem entirely

Comment: Holy s#it. that fix the whole problem.
actually, initially I tested using SoapUI software to get the correct request structure. And then I just copy over the headers from SoapUI into my code.
Didnt realize that's the real culprit. Many thanks man